# Yii2 Matching all values in IN clause

Tags: mysql, yii2

Im trying to get a query which matches all values within an IN clause. This is what I have right now in UsersSearch.php model:

```
    $categoryIdsMatching = UsersCategoriesAssn::find()
        ->select('userID')
        ->distinct(true)
        ->joinWith('userCategory')
            ->andWhere(['IN', 'usersCategories.id', $this->catNameSearch])
        ->column();
    $query->andWhere(['userID'=>$categoryIdsMatching]);
```

But it gets records matching at least one of the values... How can I set that andWhere clause to match all values instead of some of them?

Comment: This is how it's supposed to be when using [MySQLs IN Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). Besides one value that has to match all values does not sound right. Why don't you compare to just one value (if they are all the same)? Please clarify your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @abi. I have a dropdown list with multi select and i want to get records matching all selected values from that dropdown

Comment: So you have multiple category ids and and want to find all users who are in exactly those categories, right? You can try to do a join for every category with a simple '=' operator and afterwards sort out the results which have NULL values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be something similiar to:

```
$categoryIdsMatching = UsersCategoriesAssn::find()
    ->select('userID')
    ->distinct(true)
    ->joinWith('userCategory')
        ->andWhere(['IN', 'usersCategories.id', $this->catNameSearch])
        ->groupBy('userTable.userID')
        ->having('COUNT(userTable.userID) ='.count($this->catNameSearch));
```

There is propably no other way to filter IN operator to match all values in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

**Yii2 where in clause**

Model :

```
//GET MULTIPLE AREA
    public function getAreaSelected() {
        //GET SAVE COMMA SEPERARED VALUE CONVERT IN TO ARRAY
        $areaArray = explode(",", $this->attributes['selected_area']);
        $query = AreaMaster::find()->where(['IN', 'id', $areaArray])->all();
        return $query; //$this->hasMany(AreaMaster::className(), ['IN', 'id', $pks]);
    }
```

VIEW FILE :

```
<?php 
  print '<pre>';
  print_r($model->areaSelected);
  exit;
  ?>
```